# Imagen responsive background en móviles

Tags: html, css

Desarrollo una app para dispositivos móviles, y deseo colocar una `img` de fondo. Quiero que se adapte a cualquier tamaño de móvil, y permanezca siempre centrada horizontal y vertical (es un logo). No he podido lograrlo, ni con queries ni css. Les agradeceré si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias !

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 361px) {
  .imahome {
    max-width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.15;
    margin-top: 6%;
    background-position: center center;
  }
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .imahome {
    max-width: 70%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 0.15;
    padding-top: 50%;
    background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="center-ima imahome" src="https://lorempixel.com/600/400/cats" />
</div>
```

Comment: Si no muestras tu código es prácticamente imposible ayudarte, **es importante que leas [ask]**

Comment: Esta pregunta parece un duplicado de otras preguntas ya existente en Stack Overflow en español. Busca sobre [centrar verticalmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=centrar+verticalmente) y encontrarás muchos resultados, de los que seguramente te valga alguno.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con estas dos propiedades:
- background-size: cover;
- background-position: center;

Llamando directamente desde css la imagen.

```
background-image: url(tuimagenchida123.jpg);
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
background-size: cover;      
background-position: center;
```

Espero y te sirva de algo.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al crear imágenes responsives debes tener varios factores a tomar en cuenta caballero.

- **1-Saber con que tamaño juegas:** En este punto me refiero a que si tu
  imagen es de un tamaño muy pequeño para hacerla responsive tendrás
  muchos inconvenientes , el primero es que no se vera bien en tamaños
  de dispositivos grandes porque por simple lógica es muy pequeña y al
  aplicarle propiedades sobre ella lo que harás sera estirarla.
- **2-Saber ubicar la imagen:** En este punto deberás orientar tu imagen que
  pueda ser visible y lo mas importante llamativa, en el fondo de tu
  aplicación
- **3-Saber jugar con las proporciones y tratar de no repetirla en el espacio que no relleno.**

Para esto tengo estos códigos sencillos:

```
introducir el código aquí
body{
    background-image: url("../img/fondo.png"); //Directorio de tu imagen
    background-repeat: no-repeat; //No se repite imagen si no ocupa el tamaño
    background-size: cover; //Ocupado todo el espacio de la pantalla
    background-position: center; //Posiciona la imagen en el centro
}
```

**Nota:** Si esto no te funciona debes buscar otras técnicas un poco mas elaboradas, quizás con **bootstrap** o con algún **framework,** la mayoría de las veces nuestras imágenes deben ser de muy buena resolución o por así decirlo grandes para que se puedan posicionar como fondo de nuestra web.